# Is "thus forth" valid English, and if so, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Is "thus forth" valid English, and if so, what does it mean? Searching through Google, this can be found in place of therefore and thenceforth/henceforth, but I don't see any specific dictionary definitions.

Comment: He went out of the castle and thus forth to his demise.

Comment: @Jim Explaining that example would make a good answer

Comment: Yeah, I agree that’s a good example, and “therefore ahead” (directly translating the two words individually) isn’t a meaning I had considered. This came up based on seeing it used in place of “therefore” or as a synonym of “thenceforth.” An example I found online: “Our efforts to continue to care for our patients, have thus forth, been the confounding factor in our overall company’s performance.” This doesn’t seem correct to me.

Comment: Another one is this Reddit thread where it’s defined as “from this point forward” - is that correct?: https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/t6dvqm/does_thus_forth_change_the_meaning_of_this/